# django query filtering - individual results

Tags: django

I have a query set and I'm using filter : `.... = testResult.objects.filter(topic = "1")` I have multiple topics and I want the query to applied to each topic individually - so i.e. 5 topics `topic = 1`, `topic = 2` .... `topic = 5`. I want to know is there a way round duplicating the query 5 times? so having to do `testResult.objects.filter(topic = "1")` ... then the query 5 times... If I don't set the filter the value returned will be the score across all the topics - and I infact want the score of each individual topics. I can currently do this but I'm using duplication code which ideally I don't want. I though there'd be something simple i.e. `topic = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question requires you to know 2 things:

1. `__in` lookup which allows you to filter using multiple values: `Model.objects.filter(topic__in=[1, 2, 3, 4])`. [Django' docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in)
2. `Group by` which allows you to group the data "together". [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values)

I'm only pointing out to the docs so you can read about it and understand what's happening.

Comment: still trying to do this so I've got testResult.objects.filter(topic__in = [1,2,3,4]).values('topic').aggregate(all my working out here) -> this still only returns the result for id 1 - Correct idea?

Comment: hey, sorry that was just an example. If you're filtering by `ids` and `topic` is a foreignkey then: `testResult.objects.filter(topic__id__in = [1,2,3,4])`. good progress so far :), you'll nail it in no time.